# Problems with NDSolve, have a problem of reducing Numerical errors

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying solve differential equation subject to boundary condition. Here is my code:

```
 \[Lambda] = 1.5; k = 0.5; a = 1/(30*Pi); \[Zeta] = 3;
 \[CapitalLambda] = (\[Lambda]^2 (Cosh[3] - 1))/(Cosh[3] - \[Lambda]^2 + (\[Lambda]^2 - 1) Cosh[Z [t] 6/(10 Pi) - 3]);

L1 = NDSolve[{D[Z[t], 
  t] ==  (Sqrt[\[Zeta] + 
     1])/(\[CapitalLambda] Sqrt[\[Zeta] Exp[-k Exp[a t] Sin[
          1/10 Z[t]]] + Exp[-k Sin[1/10 Z[t]]]]), (Z[0] == 0)}, 
Z, {t, 0, 1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 38];
 SOL1A[t_] := Z[t] /. L1;
 Tend = FindRoot[SOL1A[t] == 10 Pi , {t, 2}, AccuracyGoal -> 1000, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 1000, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
SOL1C = Parallelize[Table[z = j Pi/100;
M1 = NDSolve[{D[Z[t], 
     t] ==  (Sqrt[\[Zeta] + 
        1])/(\[CapitalLambda] Sqrt[\[Zeta] Exp[-k Exp[a t] Sin[
             1/10 Z[t]]] + Exp[-k Sin[1/10 Z[t]]]]), (Z[
      t /. Tend] == z)}, Z, {t, 0, 1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 38]; 
SOL1B[t_] := Z[t] /. M1;
T0 = FindRoot[SOL1B[t] == 0, {t, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 1000, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 1000, WorkingPrecision -> 100];
Clear[SOL1B];
Clear[M1];
{z, T0[[1, 2]]}, {j, 0, 999, 1}]];
SOL1C = Append[SOL1C, {10 Pi, 0}];

G = Interpolation[SOL1C];
K[t_] := - D[G[t], t];
P1 = Plot[-(G'[z0]), {z0, 0, 10 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

Now if plot G I will get

[image]

It seems that it has a lot of error at the first part of the graph but overall trend is correct. However I don't know how to reduce this error. I would like to ask you for some advice in this matter.

Then if if try to plot P1 if will get this

[image]

However from the analysis this function could not get any negative values in addition to that when Z[t]=5 Pi, -G'(5 Pi) = 2.25 from the analysis and G=0 at 10 Pi.

I tried to increase precision for the second NDSolve so I made

```
M1 = NDSolve[{D[Z[t], 
 t] ==  (Sqrt[\[Zeta] + 
    1])/(\[CapitalLambda] Sqrt[\[Zeta] Exp[-k Exp[a t] Sin[
         1/10 Z[t]]] + Exp[-k Sin[1/10 Z[t]]]]), (Z[
  t /. Tend] == z)}, Z, {t, 0, 1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 38, PrecisionGoal->18];
```

However when I plot G and P1 I will end up with
[image]

and

[image]

Then the first part seems alright although not totally correct as the value of -(G'(5 Pi)=2.25. I tried to combine both method to get more realistic solution but failed as it will produce another strange picture. May I ask you for any advice for me to get the correct solution and reduce the numerical error.

Comment: Have you explored `WorkingPrecision`?

Comment: I tried but it went running for a while like couple of hours with no results.